# Dual Screen Maximize issue on Left Screen after installation / removal of NVidia drivers

Tags: 13.04, nvidia, compiz, multiple-monitors

I've recently installed a fresh 13.04 Ubuntu 64-bits version on my DELL Latitude laptop and the OS built-in display manager was handling fine the dual monitor mode.

As I wished to have Nvidia driver to have a better experience I followed these steps to get it: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-ringtail-nvidia.html

However, after installing NVidia proprietary drivers, my Ubuntu was failing to start properly, and after system start-up, only the desktop was appearing, with no Unity, nor Launcher nor Dash appearing.

Then I could succesfully remove NVidia drivers by doing the following steps:

1. Switch to console mode: <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd>
2. `sudo service lightdm stop`
3. `sudo apt-get remove --purge`
4. `sudo X -configure`
5. `sudo mv xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
6. `sudo start lightdm`

**After all this, system was working again, but with this annoying issue: when I try to maximize any window, it always goes maximized to the display on the right.**

Also the mouse cursor vanishes on the screen if I drag it to the right edge of the right monitor, and reappears only when I move the cursor back to the left screen.

I have already extensively googled for similar issues reported by other users, and tried some solutions, but the issue still happens for me.

**Didn't work for me:**

> - using launchpad with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>SUPER</kbd> <kbd>arrow keys</kbd>
> - installing COMPIZ config settings manager
> - setting external monitor as primary instead of secondary
> - "dconf reset -f /org/compiz/" followed by "unity --reset-icons &disown"

Any help would be MUCH appreciated, as for now the only solution for this would be reinstalling the whole OS   : '(

**> Additional info:**
 This is the following info about my Video card:

```
~$: lspci | grep VGA

 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [NVS 4200M] (rev a1)
```

Regards,
Alysson

Comment: Do you have a nvidia card with optimus??? They give a lot of trouble but try bumblebee (if you have a optimus card). It's not perfect but it fixes a lot of problems (dual screen options do not yet work perfectly but with a bit of work you can make it work)

Comment: Hi, I have a NVIDIA card with optimus, and I've just updated the question with this info..I'm still new with Linux, so I don't know about bumblebee. I will google it here and give it a try. Thanks :)

Comment: Just an update, I've just installed bumblebee but the issue is still the same thing :'(
Followed this tutorial here: http://www.howtogeek.com/124685/how-to-make-nvidias-optimus-work-on-linux/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you've installed bumblebee what did you do to enable the dual monitor options??

bumblebee has some issues with dual monitor computers.
here's a way to make it work correctly (please keep in mind that some hardware may be unfit for this and will not work (properly)).

https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Multi-monitor-setup

Comment: Much thanks Arno. So yesterday after installing bumblebee, I went to compiz config manager and changed again lot of settings related to screen behaviour, as I did before. It still didn't fix the issue, then today after login into my laptop, it worked fine! Didn't need to follow these latest instructions, but I believe bumblebee+compiz was the solution for this issue. 
Much thanks!!

Comment: Yeah, it needs a reboot. The tutorial makers thought it was kinda obvious but for new users it really isn't.
I should have mentioned it, knowing you're new at this, sorry.